# Update SQL Result displayed in PHP page without having to refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display the number of entries in a MySQL table in a PHP page without having to refresh the page.

Display.php

```
<?php $con= mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$num_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $con);
$num = mysql_num_rows($num_sql); ?>

There are <?php echo $num; ?> entries.
```

After some research I believe I will have to implement a client side script, perhaps jquery but I am quite unexperienced in that sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use meta tag for auto-reload page. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jquery code should work:

```
 setInterval(function(){       
     $.get('display.php',function(data){
         $('#myDiv').html(data);
     });       
 },3000);
```

This will update the contents of the div with id of 'mydiv' with the contents of display.php every 3 seconds.

Comment: thankyou smistry! happy about your quick and effective reply.

Comment: if i could vote you up i would but i dont have enough rep, when i do i will come back and vote you up. cheers